# Weird bug in Pandas and Numpy regarding multithreading

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Most of the Numpy's function will enable multithreading by default.

for example, I work on a 8-cores intel cpu workstation, if I run a script

```
import numpy as np    
x=np.random.random(1000000)
for i in range(100000):
    np.sqrt(x)
```

the linux `top` will show 800% cpu usage during running like
[image] 
Which means numpy automatically detects that my workstation has 8 cores, and `np.sqrt` automatically use all 8 cores to accelerate computation.

However, I found a weird bug. If I run a script

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)))
df+df
x=np.random.random(1000000)
for i in range(100000):
    np.sqrt(x)
```

the cpu usage is 100%!!.
[image] **It means that if you plus two pandas DataFrame before running any numpy function, the auto multithreading feature of numpy is gone without any warning!** This is absolutely not reasonable, why would Pandas dataFrame calculation affect Numpy threading setting? Is it a bug? How to work around this?

---

PS:

I dig further using Linux `perf` tool.

running first script shows

[image]

While running second script shows

[image]

So both script involves `libmkl_vml_avx2.so`, while the first script involves additional `libiomp5.so` which seems to be related to openMP.

And since vml means intel vector math library, so according to vml doc I guess at least below functions are all automatically multithreaded

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC I updated my post, hope it is now clear

Comment: I think more information is needed like np, pandas, version, CPU, OS type... I cannot reproduce on my machine. It does not utilized multiple CPUs in both codes.

Comment: @hunzter OK, here is informations: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
numpy     1.17.2  py37haad9e8e_0
pandas    0.25.1  py37he6710b0_0
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1680 v4 @ 3.40GHz.     PS. I use anaconda

Comment: As far as I can tell NumPy itself doesn't make use of multiprocessing, so I'm not sure how to handle this question...

Comment: Forgot to add: _Most of the Numpy's function will enable multithreading by default._ doesn't seem to be true. Can you provide some sort of justification? How do you know that `numpy.sqrt()` is what is (allegedly) using multiple cores?

Comment: @AMC I updated my post which proves that numpy.sqrt uses mkl lib and involves openmp. Actually as simple as ndarray addtion also auto multithreaded

Comment: Huh. I don't remember ordinary ufuncs invoking OpenMP. Maybe that's new, or maybe I missed it in the code before.

Comment: What happens if you do the `numpy` work, then import and use `pandas`, and then repeat the `numpy` work?

Comment: @DavisHerring Hi, I tried. That doesn't change anything. As long as pandas arithmetic things comes in, numpy is not threading any more

Comment: Could you please check this:
`import numpy as np

    import pandas as pd

    import os

    os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = '4'

    print(os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"])
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)))
    df+df
    print(os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"])
    a = np.random.random((20000000, 3))
    b = np.random.random((3, 30))
    for _ in range(10):
    c = np.dot(a, b)`

Comment: @StasBuzuluk Actually, `np.dot` doesn't have a threading problem. `np.dot` probably belong to mkl blas, while `np.sqrt` belong to mkl vml. Though "MKL_NUM_THREADS" printed to be 4 after `df+df`, however, `np.sqrt` is still not multithreaded

Comment: your `df+df` should have done nothing, since numpy / pandas had some native binding, that might scan your current code piece, it may had something to do with lazy evaluation, consider try, 1: do this plus before and after such .sqrt, then try append another sqrt block ,2: tweak the range or random statement ?

Comment: for your info, on Windows, a 4 core 8 thread laptop installation, even your first code piece just occupies 1/8, 12.5% CPU at peak.

Comment: @JackWu Hi, thank you for comment. Do you use anaconda on windows? In my case numpy is threading because it is linking to intel MKL which is provided by anaconda

Comment: @user15964 , ops, I use a freshly installed raw Python / pip, thus I don't even have that mkl environment variable, it surprised me a little bit since it did not raise any native build problem while pip install pandas / numpy. Will try anaconda!

Comment: @user15964 after anaconda installed, I'm using 50% of my CPU, could see 4 threads, at libiomp5md.dll, will try out your other code piceces to see if any differences.

Comment: @user15964 similar scenario observed, i could visaulize some of the thread / stack via "process explorer", similiar to yours

Comment: @user15964 you should try `htop` instead of `top` since the former will should you `cpu_usage` at the core level

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pandas uses [`numexpr`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#numexpr-2-0-user-guide) under the hood to calculate some operations, and `numexpr` sets the maximal number of threads for vml to 1, when [it is imported](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/numexpr/__init__.py#L50):

```
# The default for VML is 1 thread (see #39)
set_vml_num_threads(1)
```

and it gets imported by pandas when `df+df` is evaluated in [expressions.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b5500114d2ab9153615dd435370ed76f85a0810d/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py#L19):

```
from pandas.core.computation.check import _NUMEXPR_INSTALLED

if _NUMEXPR_INSTALLED:
   import numexpr as ne
```

However, Anaconda distribution also uses vml-functionality for such functions as `sqrt`, `sin`, `cos` and so on - and once `numexpr` set the maximal number of vml-threads to 1, the numpy-functions no longer use parallelization.

The problem can be easily seen in gdb (using your slow script):

```
>>> gdb --args python slow.py
(gdb) b mkl_serv_domain_set_num_threads
function "mkl_serv_domain_set_num_threads" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (mkl_serv_domain_set_num_threads) pending.
(gbd) run
Thread 1 "python" hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fffee65cd70 in mkl_serv_domain_set_num_threads () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
(gdb) bt 
#0  0x00007fffee65cd70 in mkl_serv_domain_set_num_threads () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
#1  0x00007fffe978026c in _set_vml_num_threads(_object*, _object*) () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numexpr/interpreter.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#2  0x00005555556cd660 in _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords () at /tmp/build/80754af9/python_1553721932202/work/Objects/call.c:694
...
(gdb) print $rdi
$1 = 1
```

i.e. we can see, `numexpr` sets number of threads to 1. Which is later used when vml-sqrt function is called:

```
(gbd) b mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7fffee65a900
(gdb) (gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 1 "python" hit Breakpoint 2, 0x00007fffee65a900 in mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffee65a900 in mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
#1  0x00007ffff01fcea9 in mkl_vml_serv_threader_d_1i_1o () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
#2  0x00007fffedf78563 in vdSqrt () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_lp64.so
#3  0x00007ffff5ac04ac in trivial_two_operand_loop () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

So we can see numpy uses vml's implementation of `vdSqrt` which utilizes `mkl_vml_serv_threader_d_1i_1o` to decide whether calculation should be done in parallel and it looks the number of threads:

```
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0x00007fffee65a900 in mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
0x00007ffff01fcea9 in mkl_vml_serv_threader_d_1i_1o () from /home/ed/anaconda37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so
(gdb) print $rax
$2 = 1
```

the register `%rax` has the maximal number of threads and it is 1.

Now we can use `numexpr` to [increase the number of vml-threads](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#intel-s-vml-specific-support-routines), i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10)))
df+df

#HERE: reset number of vml-threads
ne.set_vml_num_threads(8)

x=np.random.random(1000000)
for i in range(10000):
    np.sqrt(x)     # now in parallel
```

Now multiple cores are utilized!

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally, a great answer explains all. In the end, it is the `numexpr` behind the scene.

Comment: Agreed .. good digging!   Next question though .. why does numexpr push thread count to 1?   Possibly due to instability / thread-safe issues?  Instead of pushing the count back up to 8 it might be safer to move on to a thread-safe/stable version of NumPy.  Maybe also good to check this variable with the latest and greatest NumPy in case this is actually not needed anymore, hence technically a bug.

Comment: @AndrewAtrens you can take a look at https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/39 and https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/355

Answer (score 2):

Looking at numpy, it looks like, under the hood it has had on/off issues with multithreading, and depending on what version you are using you may expect to may start to see crashes when you bump up ne.set_vml_num_threads() ..

http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/ANN-NumExpr-2-7-0-Release-td47414.html

I need to get my head around how this is glued in to the python interpreter, given your code example where it seems to be somehow allowing multiple apparently synchronous/ordered calls to np.sqrt() to proceed in parallel. I guess if python interpreter is always just returning a reference to an object when it pops the stack, and in your example is just pitching those references and not assigning or manipulating them in any way it would be fine.  But if subsequent loop iterations depend on previous ones then it seems less clear how these could be safely parallelized.  Arguably silent failure / wrong results is an outcome worse than crashes.

Comment: Hi, Andrew Atrens, You are almost there. It is the problem of ne.set_vml_num_threads(). Thank you so much for your dedicated time on my issue.

Comment: Happy Trails :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your initial premise may be incorrect -

You stated: Which means numpy automatically detects that my workstation has 8 cores, and np.sqrt automatically use all 8 cores to accelerate computation.

A single function np.sqrt() cannot guess how it will next be invoked or return before it has partially completed.  There are parallelism mechanisms in python, but none are automatic.

Now, having said that, the python interpreter may be able to optimize the for loop for parallelism, which may be what you are seeing, but I strongly suspect if you look at the wall-clock time for this loop to execute it will be no different regardless if you are (apparently) using 8 cores or 1 core.

UPDATE: Having read a bit more of the comments it seems as though the multi-core behavior you are seeing is related to the anaconda distribution of the python interpreter. I took a look but was unable to find any source code for it, but it seems that the python license permits entities (like anaconda.com) to compile and distribute derivatives of the interpreter without requiring their changes to be published.

I guess that you can reach out to the anaconda folks - the behaviour you are seeing will be difficult to figure out without knowing what/if anything they've changed in the interpreter ..

Also do a quick check of the wall clock time with/without the optimization to see if it is indeed 8x faster - even if you've really got all 8 cores working instead of 1 it would be good to know if the results are actually 8x faster or if there are spinlocks in use which are still serializing on a single mutex.

Comment: Hi, Andrew Atrens. But the parallelization is not done by python, it is done by the backend of anaconda numpy which is intel MKL. And yes I have opened an issue on numpy, they suggested me to open an issue on anaconda, and I did it. However, I didn't got a single reply from anaconda yet for a week. So maybe they just ignored my report...

Comment: It’s an issue with the anaconda version/release of the python interpreter - their version utilizes openmp whereas the standard python release does not.

Comment: It’s an issue with the anaconda version/release of the python interpreter - their version links to / utilizes openmp apis whereas the standard python release interpreter does not. when I say utilizes I literally mean calling openmp api functions ‘under the hood’. As with any implicit optimization where we can’t see the source code we can only report it (as you have) and if possible attempt to work-around it.

Comment: Another thought on this .. you could re-code your application to explicitly use python multithreading libraries and not rely on the interpreter's optimizer to do it for you .. I'm thinking of thread pools .. depending on how complicated your application is, and if this is not your first go at threaded programming, this may not be too difficult.. To maintain portability use should probably try to avoid anything specific to anaconda or openmp - I'll leave this to you as I don't have time to dig into it... :)   Anyways best of luck and hope this helps de-fog what you are seeing. :) :)